# Trouble with Transparency: QGIS Icon Background Not Printing as Fully Transparent in PDFs

Tags: export, pdf, printing, transparency-opacity, icon

I create maps that incorporate a square PNG image with a transparent background using QGIS 3.16.4-Hannover and export them as PDF files for printing. The icon's transparent background is maintained within QGIS and in the exported PDF file, however the printed map does not retain the full transparency of the icon. Can anyone provide insights or solutions for this issue?

Screenshot of PDF file working correctly:

[image: Screenshot of PDF file working correctly]

Photo of printed map with transparent background clearly visible:

[image: Photo of printed map with transparent background clearly visible]